# alternative to calc() for css background positioning in android browser and chrome for android

Tags: css

Here´s the problem:

I need to possition a background image 0.3em to the left from the right edge

```
background-position: calc(100% - 0.3em) 0.3em;
```

Now, the problem is that this works on any browser except for Android Native Browser and Chrome for Android

Do you know any other way in which this can be solved using CSS only?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers understand background positioning from right edge. I'm not sure if it works on Android but give it a try:

```
background-position: right 0.3em top 0.3em;
```

This sets the position 0.3em from the top and 0.3em from the right edge.

Please note it does not work in older browsers so you need to provide a fallback.

Comment: I´ll give it a try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: This works on Chrome for Android (version 28) but not the native browser on Android 4.2.